# Robocopy won't copy from root folder

Tags: windows-7, ftp, copy, robocopy

I'm having trouble with `robocopy`.  It won't copy from "X:\files\".  It just kills the batch file without writing anything to log, but it WILL copy from "X:\files\other files".  Where "other files" is just one of many folders inside "files".  It is very strange. I want it to scan the whole directory and pull down files based on timestamp but it won't do it for the whole drive or just for that folder, only further specific folders.  Note: X:\ is a net drive mapped ftp server drive and I am trying to download over VPN.

WORKS:

```
robocopy "X:\files\this album" "C:\downloads\Test" /s /maxage:1 /log:"C:\downloads\Test\log.txt"
```

DOES NOT WORK:

```
robocopy "X:\files\" "C:\downloads\Test" /s /maxage:1 /log:"C:\downloads\Test\log.txt"
```

I don't get it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the trailing slash, or the quotes, from the source path in your example.  The command should be:

```
robocopy "X:\files" "C:\downloads\Test" /s /maxage:1 /log:"C:\downloads\Test\log.txt"
```

[*"If either the source or destination are a quoted long folder name do not include a trailing backslash as this will be treated as an escape character"*](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: ahh! amazing. worked. now if only i could get that pesky maxage command to work...

Comment: Your use `/maxage:1` would exclude all files older than 1 day.